# In our end or On our end

Tags: prepositions

I need help to explain as to why the phrase "in our end" is incorrect (or is it?) as I feel like it should be "on our end". Why is "in our end" incorrect? For example:

> We are unable to locate your order in our end.

Comment: Can you please show some example sentences to make clear how the phrase is used?

Comment: Example: We are unable to locate your order in our end. :)

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please edit the question itelf to improve it. You might like to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour), and read the [help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: We would say "We are unable to locate your order **at** our end."

Comment: I would say ***on*** *our end* or ***from*** *our end*. (***In*** *our end* is definitely not normal—and actually has a very unfortunate interpretation that is not what you want it to mean …)

Answer (score 1):

It is a mistake.

"Our end" (or "my end") refers to someone's side of an arrangement, procedure, or sometimes a point of view. You might hear:

> *From* our end, things look fine
>
> There is no problem *at* our end.

"On" our end could possibly be correct in a context where you would normally say the problem is "on" something - for example when there is interference on a telephone call, there is said to be a problem "on the line", so in such a situation you perhaps might say "there is a problem on my end (of the call/line)".

"In our end" seems the most unlikely to be used correctly, and certainly does not sound correct in the context of your example, which should be "at":

> We are unable to locate your order **at** our end.

This is because it speaks about locating something, and you would use "at" to denote a location.